# Sudden spike in legendary drop chance?

Tags: borderlands-2

So I think about a year ago, Gearbox had some tests running and eventually tripled the legendary drop rate for most items.

Very recently I've started a new playthrough with a friend and we've been coming to the OP-levels.

Before we did those, we killed the raid boss Dexiduous and actually got the Legendary Soldier class mod. Two of it. From one single kill just lying there on the ground.

The weird part about that is, that this specific class mod isn't even in the rare loot pool from Dexiduous, according to the wiki.

So we were really happy and then tried the Digistruct peak. While doing so the very first time we just got a random Mongol from a single non-badass skag.
Also we got reaaally lucky with legendaries in general.

So does anyone know if maybe Gearbox is doing some shenanigans with the drop rates again? Or does anyone else have had that much luck recently?

Because that would mean it's farming time.

Comment: You may have just gotten lucky with the drop rates, with such a small sample size (2 events?) it'd be hard to draw any conclusions

Comment: @Robotnik Alright so we also killed the four legendary loot midgets in the WIldlife Exploitation Preserve and got two more random legendaries. Also when we farmed Voraciduous about ten times we got 3 more legendary class mods. That's sadly all I can remember for now, but I know, that we got way more through all playthroughs. Also mostly on first kills of specific bosses.